# Prevent browser from sending POST requests

Tags: google-chrome, javascript

I'm trying to block facebook from sending the "message has been seen- message" the POST request url i'm trying to block is: "https://www.messenger.com/ajax/mercury/delivery_receipts.php?dpr=2"

Does anyone have any idea how i can do this? Preferably with nodejs, javascript, chrome plugins etc (i'm not looking for the already available plugins, i want to create something myself without adware and spyware)

Comment: You will have to look into writing your own plugin for that or filter it on a more general level on your system. [`chrome.webRequest`](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest) seems to be the API you can use to block a request.

Answer (score 1):

> ... chrome plugins etc (i'm not looking for the already available plugins ...

This sounds confusing. Do you want somebody to suggest a plugin which will be developed in future?

Regarding your problem, it seems to me that [HTTP Request Blocker](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/http-request-blocker/eckpjmeijpoipmldfbckahppeonkoeko?hl=en) Google Chrome extension must be suitable?